# Asp.Net Show items from db grouped by manufacturer with group heading

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2005, c#-4.0

I have a number of products in a SQL2005 DB. I have the Stored Procedure set-up to return the info as grouped rows containing 'manufacturer, model, quantitiy'.

I need to then display this content on a c# Asp.Net 4 web form grouped by manufacturer with the manufacturer as the group header. The whole data should be displayed over a 3 column layout.

So, Ive used a Datalist as this allows for the number of columns to be stipulated.

However, I can't work out an effective way to show the various products groupd by manufacturer, eg as shown below;

Toshiba
3401
3685
3699

Mitsubishi
12033b
23423nn
4444ff2

LG
344545b
523423hbb
45tvu12


RATHER THAN:

Toshiba 3401
Toshiba 3685
Toshiba 3699

Mitsubishi 12033b
Mitsubishi 23423nn
Mitsubishi 4444ff2

LG 344545b
LG 523423hbb
LG 45tvu12

Any sugestions would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not ideal but I've listed the header categories first and then called in the sub items via seperate db call on the ItemDataBound event of each row.